# How to get selected values to input values (as objects) in Spring + Thymeleaf?

Tags: spring, select, input, thymeleaf, dropdown

View: **modAnimal.html** (this is the first part of the view, after it there are input values in hidden div)

```
<form th:action="@{/animales/preModAnimal}" th:object="${animal}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formPreModAnimal">

                    <!-- INPUT TIPO DE ANIMAL -->

                    <label>Animal</label>
                            <input type="radio" th:field="*{tipo}" th:value="*{tipo.PERRO}" required /> 
                            <label></label>

                            <input type="radio" th:field="*{tipo}" th:value="*{tipo.GATO}" required /> 
                            <label></label>

                    <!-- INPUT SEXO DEL ANIMAL -->

                    <label>Sexo</label>
                            <input type="radio" th:field="*{sexo}" th:value="*{sexo.MACHO}" required /> 
                            <label>♂️</label>

                            <input type="radio" th:field="*{sexo}" th:value="*{sexo.HEMBRA}" required /> 
                            <label>♀️</label>


                    <!-- INPUT SELECT ANIMAL -->

                    <label for="selectAnimal">Animal</label>

                        <select th:fragment="animales" id="selectAnimal" required
                            class="form-control">
                            <option value="" selected="selected">Selecciona animal</option>
                            <option th:each="i : ${animales}"
                                th:text="${i.emojiTipo} + ' ' + ${i.emojiSexo} + ' - ' + ${i.nombre} + ' - ' + ${i.raza} + ' - ' + ${i.provincia.provincia} + '  (' + ${i.poblacion} + ')'"
                                th:value="${i.id}"></option>
                        </select>

            </form>
```

Depending on the selected radios, the select drop-down will be loaded with the desired values. 
This is done with jQuery

**funcionesCheck_jQuery.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[name=tipo], [name=sexo]').change(function() {

    $("#selectAnimal").load('/animales/checktiposexo', $('#formPreModAnimal :input[type=radio]').serialize());

  });
});
```

And this is the controller

**AnimalesController.java**

```
        @GetMapping("/modAnimal") public String pagMod(Model model) {

    Animal animal = new Animal();
    model.addAttribute("animal", animal);

    Sexo[] opcionesSexo = Sexo.values();
    model.addAttribute("sexos", opcionesSexo);

    Tipo[] opcionesTipo = Tipo.values();
    model.addAttribute("tipos", opcionesTipo);

    return "animales/modAnimal";
}

@GetMapping("/checktiposexo")
public String filtroTipoSexo(Model model, @RequestParam(name = "tipo", required = false) Tipo tipo,
        @RequestParam(name = "sexo", required = false) Sexo sexo) {

    List<Animal> listaAnimales;

    if (tipo == null && sexo == null) { // not working, i wanted this to act different, but nvm
        listaAnimales = animalesRepo.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("animales", listaAnimales);
    } else if (tipo != null && sexo == null) {
        listaAnimales = animalesRepo.findAllAnimalesByTipoOrSexo(tipo, sexo);
        model.addAttribute("animales", listaAnimales);
    } else if (tipo == null && sexo != null) {
        listaAnimales = animalesRepo.findAllAnimalesByTipoOrSexo(tipo, sexo);
        model.addAttribute("animales", listaAnimales);
    } else {
        listaAnimales = animalesRepo.findAllAnimalesByTipoAndSexo(tipo, sexo);
        model.addAttribute("animales", listaAnimales);
    }

    return "animales/modAnimal :: animales"; //I'm returning animales as fragment

}
```

Then I want to fill some input values with the values given in the selected option **in the same view** mentioned at begin of the post.

Everytime the selected option changes, these inputs will re-show again. They're in a div (#modificarOculto) initially hidden at begin.

**funcionesCheck_jQuery.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$( "#modificarOculto" ).hide();
$("[name=tipo], [name=sexo], #selectAnimal").change(function() {
    $('#modificarOculto').hide('300');
    $("#selectAnimal").change(function() {

    inputSelectAnimal = $("#selectAnimal")[0];
    selectAnimal = $("#selectAnimal").val();

    if(selectAnimal>0){
    $('#modificarOculto').show('slow');


    }else if(selectAnimal==0){
        $('#modificarOculto').hide('slow');
    }


    });
});
});
```

Remember, this is the part of the view below the view at begin. I want to load the selected values in these inputs.

**modAnimal.html** (again)

```
        <div class="row cajita" id="modificarOculto">

            <form th:action="@{/animales/modAnimal-submit}" id="formModAnimal"
                th:object="${animal}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    <label >Nombre</label>
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{nombre}"  class="form-control"
                            placeholder="Nombre del animal" required minlength=3
                            maxlength=50 />

                    <label>Animal</label>
                            <input type="radio" th:field="*{tipo}" th:value="*{tipo.PERRO}"required /> 
                            <label></label>

                            <input type="radio" th:field="*{tipo}" th:value="*{tipo.GATO}" required /> 
                            <label></label>


                    <label>Sexo</label>
                            <input type="radio" th:field="*{sexo}" th:value="*{sexo.MACHO}" required /> 
                            <label>♂️</label>

                            <input type="radio" th:field="*{sexo}" th:value="*{sexo.HEMBRA}" required /> 
                            <label>♀️</label>

                    <!-- INPUT PROVINCIA ANIMAL -->

                    <label>Provincia</label>
                        <select id="provincia" name="provincia" required>
                            <option value="">Load the selected provincia</option>
                            <option th:each="i : ${provincias}" th:text="${i.provincia}"
                                th:value="${i.id}">
                        </select>

                        <button type="submit" id="botonModificar">Modificar</button>

            </form>
        </div>
```

I know I need a form to submit the new values ("formModAnimal"), but... I know I don't need the form of begin ("formPreModAnimal"). What I don't really know if I would need to englobe the whole view (select part + input part) in a form together.

How could I send the data as object values from the selected value to input values? Is there any smart way to do it with Thymeleaf? 
May I be able to associate the selected value to a fragment and send it to the form "formModAnimal" and use it as animal.attribute? That would be very comfortable.

How would you do this?

I've deleted all the bootstrap divs and classes for your overview comfort. I hope everything is clear for you!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've resolved it.

This is my new jQuery function in **funcionesCheck_jQuery.js**, where I load in div $('#modificarOculto') the serialized results of the selected drop-down $("#selectAnimal").
(I don't know why can't I just take the id of the drop-down, or why @RequestParam("selectAnimal") can't take it from the view directly...)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//$("#modificarOculto").hide();
$("[name=tipo], [name=sexo], #selectAnimal").change(function() {
    $('#modificarOculto').hide('300');
    $("#selectAnimal").change(function() {

        inputSelectAnimal = $("#selectAnimal")[0];
        selectAnimal = $("#selectAnimal").val();

        if (selectAnimal > 0) {
            $('#modificarOculto').show('slow');
            $('#modificarOculto').load('/animales/animalid', $("#selectAnimal").serialize());

        } else if (selectAnimal == 0) {
            $('#modificarOculto').hide('slow');
        }

    });
});
});
```

This is managed in the controller **AnimalController.java**: @RequestMapping("/animalid"), which will return a thymeleaf fragment with the selected animal values.

```
@RequestMapping("/animalid")
public String getAnimalByID(@RequestParam(name = "selectAnimal", required = false) int idAnimal, Model model) {

    Animal animalModelo = new Animal();
    model.addAttribute("animal", animalModelo);

    Esterilizado[] opcionesEsterilizado = Esterilizado.values();
    model.addAttribute("esterilizados", opcionesEsterilizado);

    List<Provincia> listaProvincias = provinciasRepo.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("provincias", listaProvincias);


    Optional <Animal> animal = animalesRepo.findOneAnimalById(idAnimal);


    if (animal.isPresent()) {
        model.addAttribute("selectedAnimal", animal.get());
} else {
    // ERROR?
}


    return "animales/modAnimal :: selectedAnimal";
}
```

And finally, this is the second part of my View. I insert the Thymeleaf fragment inside the form and I use it as object too. This form is also ready to submit the given data to database (mapped). Now I'm working on updating the data instead inserting.

```
<div class="row cajita" id="modificarOculto">

        <div class="col-md-9 offset-1">


            <form th:action="@{/animales/modAnimal-submit}" id="formModAnimal"
                th:object="${selectedAnimal}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
                class="was-validated" th:fragment="selectedAnimal">

                <th:block th:if="${selectedAnimal != null}">


                <!-- INPUT NOMBRE ANIMAL -->

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" th:name="nombre"  th:value="${selectedAnimal.getNombre()}"  class="form-control"
                            placeholder="Nombre del animal" required minlength=3
                            maxlength=50 />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">

                    <!-- INPUT TIPO DE ANIMAL -->

                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Animal</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input type="radio" th:name="tipo" th:value="${selectedAnimal.tipo.PERRO}"  th:checked="${selectedAnimal.getTipo()} == ${selectedAnimal.tipo.PERRO}"
                                class="form-check-input" required > <label class="form-check-label"></label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input type="radio" th:name="tipo" th:value="${selectedAnimal.tipo.GATO}" th:checked="${selectedAnimal.getTipo()} == ${selectedAnimal.tipo.GATO}"
                                class="form-check-input" required > <label class="form-check-label"></label>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <!-- INPUT SEXO DEL ANIMAL -->

                    <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Sexo</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input type="radio" th:name="sexo" th:value="${selectedAnimal.sexo.MACHO}" th:checked="${selectedAnimal.getSexo()} == ${selectedAnimal.sexo.MACHO}"
                                class="form-check-input" required > <label class="form-check-label">♂️</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input type="radio" th:name="sexo" th:value="${selectedAnimal.sexo.HEMBRA}" th:checked="${selectedAnimal.getSexo()} == ${selectedAnimal.sexo.HEMBRA}"
                                class="form-check-input" required > <label class="form-check-label">♀️</label>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <!-- INPUT RAZA -->

                    <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label" for="nombre">Raza</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="text" th:name="raza" th:value="${selectedAnimal.getRaza()}" class="form-control"
                            placeholder="Raza del animal" required minlength=3 maxlength=100 />
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group row">

                    <!-- INPUT FECHA DE NACIMIENTO -->

                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="fnac">Fecha de
                        nacimiento</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="date" th:name="fnac" th:id="fnac" th:value="${selectedAnimal.getFnac()}" class="form-control"
                            min="1990-01-01" required />
                    </div>

                    <!-- INPUT ESTERILIZADO -->

                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Esterilizado</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <th:block th:each="i : ${esterilizados}">
                            <div class="form-check">
                                <input type="radio" th:name="esterilizado" th:id="'esterilizado'+${iStat.index+1}" required
                                    th:value="${i}" class="form-check-input" th:checked="${selectedAnimal.getEsterilizado() == i}" > <label
                                    class="form-check-label" th:for="'esterilizado'+${iStat.index+1}"
                                    th:text="${#strings.capitalize(#strings.toLowerCase(i))}">Esterilizado</label>
                            </div>
                        </th:block>

                    </div>


                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">

                    <!-- INPUT PROVINCIA ANIMAL -->

                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="provincia">Provincia</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <select id="provincia" th:name="provincia" required
                                class="form-control">
                                <option th:each="i : ${provincias}" th:text="${i.provincia}"
                                    th:value="${i.id}"
                                    th:selected="${selectedAnimal.getProvincia().getId() == i.id}">
                            </select>

                            <!-- Si fuera un valor enum  <td><select th:field="*{provincia}">
                        <option th:each="i : ${provincias}" th:text="${i.toString()}"
                            th:value="${i}"></option></select></td>-->

                    </div>

                    <!-- INPUT POBLACION ANIMAL -->

                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="fnac">Población</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" th:name="poblacion" th:value="${selectedAnimal.getPoblacion()}" class="form-control"
                            required minlenght=2 maxlength=50 />
                    </div>
                </div>



                <!-- INPUT FOTO ANIMAL -->

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="file">Foto</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">

                        <input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*"
                            class="form-control-file" id="validatedCustomFile" required />
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">Ningún archivo seleccionado</div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- INPUT FOTO EN LAS SOMBRAS -->
                    <label for="foto" style="display: none;">Foto</label> <input
                        type="text" th:name="foto"
                        th:value="${selectedAnimal.getFoto()}" maxlength=200
                        style="display: none;" />

                </div>

                <!-- INPUT DESCRIPCION ANIMAL -->

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="descripcion">Descripción</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <textarea class="form-control" required rows="5" cols="50"
                            th:name="descripcion" minlength=50 maxlength=255
                            th:text="${selectedAnimal.getDescripcion()}" th:value="${selectedAnimal.getDescripcion()}"
                            placeholder="Historia, personalidad, enfermedades, comportamiento con otras mascotas"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success float-right"
                            id="botonUpdateAnimal">Actualizar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div th:if="${message}" th:text="${message}"
                    th:class="${'alert ' + alertClass}" ></div>

                </th:block>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
```